# Get a link to paged(<!--nextpage-->) part?

Tags: permalinks, pages, paged, nextpage

I want to get a link (like `get_permalink($id)` ) to it's specific page of a post (created by `<!--nexpage-->` tag)..

how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried with next_post_link() method?

Comment: @WisdmLabs that doesnt help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for:

```
_wp_link_page( $page_number );
```

Must be used inside loop, and it return the opening tag:

http://wpseek.com/function/_wp_link_page/